# Wait N seconds for actor to return in Scala

Tags: scala, asynchronous, timeout, akka, akka-actor

I am working on a project that uses Akka actors to handle some backend processes. I have created a method that calls the Actor, however it does not return instantly. Therefore, I want a timeout of 5 seconds, so if the Actor returns within the 5 seconds, my method will return this, if not, then a default value will be returned.

Just to be clear, the method calling the Actor's method is not itself within another actor, it is just a regular class. Secondly, I have tried using `Timeout` and `Await`, and even when importing them, it says they are not found.

Example code:

service.scala

```
override def foo(): MyType = {
      var toReturn = MyType(fale, None, None)
      implicit val timeout: Timeout = 5.seconds
      val result = Await.result(myActor ? fetchData, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[MyType]
      if(result.healthy == true){
          toReturn = result
      }
      toReturn     
  }
```

actorClass.scala

```
override def receive: Receive = {
    case fetchData => 
      actorFoo()
    case _ =>
      logger.error("...")
  }

...

private def actorFoo(): MyType = {
    val num1 = list1.size
    val num2 = list2.size
    val data = MyType(true, Some(num1), Some(num2))
    println(data)
    data
  }
```

When I run this code, the `data` is printed within the `actorFoo` method, but then nothing happens after. I even tried printing "SUCCESS" after the `Await` to ensure it has not broken, but even that is not printed.

Comment: You need to provide some code and, in particular, explain what you mean by "calling the Actor's method". You should never, ever call a method on an Actor, you should only ever send it a message. If you need a reply in a given time, use the `ask` pattern with a timeout.

Comment: Hi, apologies regarding the terminology, I am new to Actors. And I can provide some example code. Furthermore, I have tried the ``ask`` and ``Timeout`` approach, and when I try to print the result, nothing is printed, nor is the correct outcome generated.

Comment: What exception handling do you have? `Await.result` might throw an exception in which case any code following it will not be called. (And get rid of that `var` since it is really not necessary at all, just return the failure value in an `else` branch)

Answer (score 1):

The ask pattern requires a reply to be sent, and your actor doesn't send a reply:

```scala
override def receive: Receive = {
    case fetchData => 
      actorFoo()
    case _ =>
      logger.error("...")
  }


private def actorFoo(): MyType = {
    val num1 = list1.size
    val num2 = list2.size
    val data = MyType(true, Some(num1), Some(num2))
    println(data)
    data
  }
```

`actorFoo()` has a result type of `MyType`, but the result gets thrown away via a silent conversion to `Unit` (it's a Scala wart... enabling `-Ywarn-value-discard` will show the warning).

To explicitly send the result of `actorFoo()` to the requestor, try something like:

```scala
override def receive: Receive = {
  case fetchData =>
    sender ! actorFoo()
}
```